# Warning: Singleton variables

Tags: prolog

Подскажите, попробовал в онлайн трансляторе пролога [(https://rextester.com/l/prolog_online_compiler](https://rextester.com/l/prolog_online_compiler)) записать факт, как в туториалах описано:

```
parent(Maria, Daria).
```

Получил Warning:

```
Warning: source_file.prolog:5:
    Singleton variables: [Maria,Daria]
```

Почему выдаёт этот warning? Нужно было заранее как-то объявить переменные?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Интерпретатор Prolog подсказывает вам, что эти переменные могут быть заменены на анонимную переменную `_`, так как нигде больше в данном предложении не участвуют.

Если вы хотели задать факт того, что Мария является родителем Дарьи, то следует использовать константы, которые в прологе пишутся с маленькой буквы, т.е:

```
parent(maria, daria).
```